# Given a point in 3D and a voxel grid, find the corresponding voxel(s)

Tags: python, graphics, 3d, voxel

I am a newbie in 3D computer vision, currently solving the following problem in Python:

I have a voxel grid in 3D and a random point in 3D. I want to find which voxel this point falls into. Is there some simple way how to do this?

More advanced question is - is there some way to interpolate between voxels? Meaning if a point is near the boundary between two voxels, can I get the corresponding voxels and some weights?

Thanks!

Comment: question requires more details. please review [ask], [mre], [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0):

Floor every dimension of the point and multiply by voxel size for the exact voxel you're looking for

Comment: But this works only if the voxel grid is aligned with world axes right? What about when the voxel grid is aligned differently and possibly shifted away from the origin?

Comment: If the grid has offset, add it to the point position and do the same calculation